Set default value in select-options using Angular 17
I want to set Male as the default value.
Here's the Angular HTML:
<select name="gender" id="gender" [(ngModel)]="registration.gender">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>

My .TS file:
export class Registration implements OnInit {
  public patients = [] as Patient[];
  public patient = {} as Patient;
  public registration = {} as Registration;
  //registration.gender = 'male';
  gender = 'male';
}

I have tried several other methods but I'm unable to set male as the default selected value! What can I try next?

does this help you stackblitz

I knew it was something that simple. Please post this as an answer.

We can just initialize the value with the property gender as male.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <select name="gender" id="gender" [(ngModel)]="registration.gender">
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
      <option value="others">Others</option>
    </select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public patients = [] as any[];
  public patient = {} as any;
  // this will also work, else go for ngOnInit!
  //public registration = { gender: 'male' } as any;
  public registration = {} as any;
  //registration.gender = 'male';
  gender = 'male';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registration.gender = 'male';
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank You so much. Your answer is slightly different from the above comment. I used the code in your comment which is: ngOnInit() { this.registration.gender = 'male'; }

@ElaineByene I will add that also in comments!
